# React. Module parse failed

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

When I was trying to use the library with a third part dependency (created also by me) I got this error:

```
./node_modules/@pack/dashboard-react-sdk/dashboard.js 135073:10
[0] Module parse failed: Unexpected token (135073:10)
[0] File was processed with these loaders:
[0]  * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
[0] You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
[0] | 
[0] | class ChartOptionsFactory {
[0] >   options = new Map().set(dashboardTypings.ChartTypings.ChartTypes.LINE, commonjsGlobal.createLineChart).set(dashboardTypings.ChartTypings.ChartTypes.LINE_SMOOTH, commonjsGlobal.createSmoothLineChart).set(dashboardTypings.ChartTypings.ChartTypes.PIE, commonjsGlobal.createPieChart).set(dashboardTypings.ChartTypings.ChartTypes.PIE_DONUT, commonjsGlobal.createPieDonutChart).set(dashboardTypings.ChartTypings.ChartTypes.BAR, commonjsGlobal.createBarChart).set(dashboardTypings.ChartTypings.ChartTypes.BAR_HORIZONTAL, commonjsGlobal.createHorizontalBarChart).set(dashboardTypings.ChartTypings.ChartTypes.GAUGE, commonjsGlobal.createGaugeChart).set(dashboardTypings.ChartTypings.ChartTypes.SCATTER, commonjsGlobal.createScatterChart);
[0] | 
[0] |   createLineChart() {
```

As I understand webpack blaming some JS options that can't be added to the final bundle.
In all three packages tsconfig target is set to 'ESNext'.

This is the part of code mentioned in error text:

```
import { ChartTypings } from "@pack/dashboard-typings";
export class ChartOptionsFactory implements IChartOptionsFactory {
    
      private readonly options: Map<ChartTypings.ChartTypes, () => ChartOptions> = new Map<ChartTypings.ChartTypes, () => ChartOptions>()
        .set(ChartTypings.ChartTypes.LINE, this.createLineChart)
        .set(ChartTypings.ChartTypes.LINE_SMOOTH, this.createSmoothLineChart)
        .set(ChartTypings.ChartTypes.PIE, this.createPieChart)
        .set(ChartTypings.ChartTypes.PIE_DONUT, this.createPieDonutChart)
        .set(ChartTypings.ChartTypes.BAR, this.createBarChart)
        .set(ChartTypings.ChartTypes.BAR_HORIZONTAL, this.createHorizontalBarChart)
        .set(ChartTypings.ChartTypes.GAUGE, this.createGaugeChart)
        .set(ChartTypings.ChartTypes.SCATTER, this.createScatterChart);
    ....
```

How this can be solved?

Comment: Try lowering tsconfig target.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved here https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8656#issuecomment-456010969

Or remove folder node_modules then re-install by using yarn

Comment: Maybe you can add part of the code from the link you shared in the case the page would stop working.